# Powering a 6v servo and 12v servo

Tags: battery

In my project, there are two types of servos ( 6v and 12v supply needs ).
I need to power with the same battery. 
How should I go about it?
Use a 6v battery with a step-up voltage regulator? 
How does that impact the battery power calculations?
If voltage regulator should be used please recommend one.
Thanks
Ro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking with a 6 volt battery would require you to use something like a boost converter, but the current to the servos would go down as a result. Current lowers in your circuit due to the increase in voltage as the equation P=V*I must be satisfied, where your P (power) is constant.

It will most likely be easier to use a 12 volt battery with a voltage regulatory to step down to 6 volts.

Assuming you wont go over 1.5A on the 6V motor, you can use something like this:

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/micro-commercial-co/MC7806CT-BP/MC7806CT-BPMS-ND/804683